# Python подключение к базе данных

Tags: mysql, python, python-2.x

Есть файл - b15.local.sql
как подключится к базе данных и с помощью каких библиотек это сделать?
Можно с примером, так как

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",    # your host, usually localhost
                 user="root",         # your username
                 passwd="31415",  # your password
                 db="b15")
```

выдаёт ошибку о том что база данных не существует, при db = 'b15.local' и db='b15.local.sql' выдают ту же ошибку

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python

Comment: Уточните вопрос. Что конкретно вы хотите сделать? Подключиться к MySQL можно разными способами, используя разные модули...

Comment: Я хочу подключится к базе с помощью библиотеки MySQL для дальнейшей работы с данными, но примеры из сети по типу import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",    # your host, usually localhost
                     user="root",         # your username
                     passwd="31415",  # your password
                     db="b15")   
Выдают ошибки и мне нужен наглядный пример того как подключится и получить данные

Comment: *Есть файл - b15.local.sql* Скорее всего, это бэкап - скрипт воссоздания БД, а не сама база данных. Его надо развернуть (выполнить) на существующем MySQL-сервере. После чего можно подключаться к созданной и заполненной БД - если восстановление обойдётся без ошибок.

Comment: "Согласен с предыдущим оратором", посмотрите, что у вас в файле, если просто текстовые инструкции SQL, то это действительно бэкап (выгрузка) из БД.

Comment: Да, скорее всего, его же можно просто исполнить что бы превратить в полноценную БД?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам уже ответили. Для того что бы работать с базой Вам необходимо установить MySQL сервер где и развернуть дамп https://habrahabr.ru/post/105954/ если вы хотите работать с базой именно как с файлом то возможно пригодится вот такой конвертер https://github.com/dumblob/mysql2sqlite и модуль sqlite3